# PHP Warning: extract() expects parameter 1 to be array

Tags: php

In Error log I got this error `PHP Warning: extract() expects parameter 1 to be array` this will overload server an increase CPU usage. what's wrong in my php function.

```
<?php
function rel2abs($rel, $base) {
  if (empty($rel)) $rel = ".";
  if (parse_url($rel, PHP_URL_SCHEME) != "" || strpos($rel, "//") === 0) return $rel; 
  if ($rel[0] == "#" || $rel[0] == "?") return $base.$rel; 
  extract(parse_url($base)); 
  $path = isset($path) ? preg_replace('#/[^/]*$#', "", $path) : "/"; 
  if ($rel[0] == '/') $path = ""; 
  $port = isset($port) && $port != 80 ? ":" . $port : "";
  $auth = "";
  if (isset($user)) {
    $auth = $user;
    if (isset($pass)) {
      $auth .= ":" . $pass;
    }
    $auth .= "@";
  }
  $abs = "$auth$host$path$port/$rel"; //Dirty absolute URL
  for ($n = 1; $n > 0; $abs = preg_replace(array("#(/\.?/)#", "#/(?!\.\.)[^/]+/\.\./#"), "/", $abs, -1, $n)) {} 
  return $scheme . "://" . $abs;
}
```

Comment: As seen in the [documentation](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.parse-url.php), on seriously malformed URLs, `parse_url()` may return false.

Comment: can you correct the function above.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in the comment above the `parse_url()` function fan return false if it's not able to parse the URL. And the `extract()` requires an array as a first parameter (not a boolean).

So instead of:

```
extract(parse_url($base));
```

You need something like this:

```
$parsedUrl = parse_url($base);
if ($parsedUrl === false) {
    throw new \RuntimeException(sprintf('Unable to parse url [%s]', $base));
}

extract($parsedUrl);
```